# Prepopulate mail client with message, recipients and attachments but don't send

Tags: email, outlook

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem:

1/ ASP Web Forms site must prepopulate email message in Outlook on local machine
2/ Must also attach attachments
3/ Must not send email - user must be able to edit the email in the mail client and manually send.

We previously had a solution but it was using an ActiveX object and we'd like to replace this as it is preventing us from working with modern browsers.

I've tried Outlook Interop which works brilliantly but only when executing the site locally. It doesn't work when running on the test server - I'm guessing its trying to open Outlook on the server rather than the workstation. Server side solutions exist, but only for creating and sending the email automatically. We need it to be edited first.

I've tried a process solution but again only works on the executing machine - so when its running on the server, tries to run on the server.

So I need a Javascript solution (or something that runs on the client side). Mailto: works locally and opens up Outlook with the prepopulated fields. But it doesn't add the attachments.

```
            string strAttachment4 = "c:\\Users\\thomsonm\\Downloads\\gvCostCodes.pdf";

string post = "mailto:" + "mark@test.com" + "?cc=mark@test.com,test.user@test.com" + "&subject=Test Message" + "&body=Please update the record for test" + "&attach=" + strAttachment4;

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "DoEmail", "window.open('"+post+"');", true);
```

Does anyone have any ideas or a solution?

Comment: Almost certain you can't do this how you want to. It might be possible if you can configure some stuff on the client computers but its a bad plan. Cant you just make a web-form that allows the user to edit the details and then post it, along with any attachments back to the server to be sent?

Comment: Yes I was thinking that might be the case. Was just hoping there might be a simpler option.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create an EML (MIME) file and let the user click to download it. Outlook will be happy to open it.

If you want the message to be unsent, make sure to set the `X-Unsent: 1` MIME header.